# Android 10 / Q / API 29 - check if video file exists

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using this code to download videos:

```
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fileURL))
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
    "/appName/example.mp4"
)
```

but need to know if the file already exists.

I tried:

```
    val file = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/appName/example.mp4")
    
    if (file.isFile) {
        Log.d(tagg, "exists")
    } else {
        Log.d(tagg, "nope")
    }
```

and it says nope

Comment: did you try with `file.exists();`

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: are you sure this is the correct path of the file ? please check it with your explorer

Comment: Well yeah in a file manager the file is in Pictures/appname/example.mp4

Comment: Bad filemanager. The path should be /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/appname/example.mp4. Now is it? Have a look at file.getAbsolutePath() too as you will see an impossible path too.

Comment: file.getAbsolutePath() gives a string that starts with /Pictures/

Comment: Yes. And such paths do not exist. And if your file manager shows such a path then use another file manager that does not byte you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> val file = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/appName/example.mp4")

That should be:

```
val file = File(Environmet.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES )+ "/appName/example.mp4")
```

On an Android 10 device your app has no access to that public diretory unless you requested legacy external storage in manifest file.

You can check existence however without that permission.

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated, doesn't work at API >= 29

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Use it. Anyhow what you did was wrong which you could conclude yourself looking at the value of file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Ok it works even though it says it's deprecated, maybe it won't work in the next API because they can't stop changing stuff that works